# Complex Analysis: Using the first method of evaluation to evaluate $\int_{c} z e^{z^2} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I could use some help on integrating the following using the first evaluation method $\int_{c} z e^{z^2} dz$ from $1$ along the axes to $i$.

To be able to use the first method, it should have $F'(z)=f(z)$, but when I take the antiderivative of $f(z)$, I get $F'(z) = z \frac{1}{2^{z+1}}e^{2z+1}$, which is not the same as $f(z)$. How do I set up this integration and how do I know that the first method of evaluation is the right method to evaluate this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your $F$ is wrong, try this $$\tfrac{d}{dz} \tfrac{1}{2} e^{z^2} = z e^{z^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since f is analytic everywhere and it has an antiderivative , its integral along a closed path will be zero and the value of the integral from point a to point b will depend only on end points a and b and not the path along which we traverse.

$F(z)=\frac{1}{2}e^{z^{2}}$. The value of the integral will be just $F(i)-F(1)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{-1}-e^{1})=\frac{-1}{2}(e-\frac{1}{e})$
Which you can verify by directly computing.

Comment: can you please tell me how you found $F(z)$?

Comment: @Sam if you differentiate this then you get the original function. That's what you are taught in integral calculus in 12th grade. $\int xe^{x^{2}}$ Substitute $t=x^{2}$ and then integrate $\int\frac{1}{2}e^{t}dt$